# Passing a parameter into a function Powershell

Tags: powershell, function, variables

I've made an email function for my Powershell script using the standard Send-email message command.

I want to pass the -body parameter into the function at various parts of the script and use a different body message depending on what gets triggered.

The function is as follows:

```
function emailHelp  {
   $smtpaddress = "help@help.com"
   $fromsmtpaddress = "needhelp@help.com"

   Send-MailMessage -To $smtpaddress -From $fromsmtpaddress -Subject 'I have an issue' -SmtpServer "1.1.1.1" -Port 25
}

---some script here---

$bodyMessage

---going to call email function---
 

emailHelp -body $bodyMessage
```

I've tried different approaches from Google but none have worked. I always get an empty body in the email sent

Help appreciated.

Thanks

Donald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Send-MailMessage** function requires `-Body` parameter to send body message (pls have a look at the reference below).

Adding the input parameter (body message) to your function helps you. In your function, the input parameter is not defined, but it is called with a parameter. Also, your `Send-MailMessage` does not have a `-Body` parameter.

In addition, you can call the function in different places with different body messages.

Code:

```
function emailHelp {
    # add parameter
    param (
        [string]$BodyMessage
    )

    $smtpaddress = "help@help.com"
    $fromsmtpaddress = "needhelp@help.com"

    # use body parameter
    Send-MailMessage -To $smtpaddress -From $fromsmtpaddress -Subject 'I have an issue' -Body $BodyMessage -SmtpServer "1.1.1.1" -Port 25
}

# ---some script here---
$bodyMessage = "body message1."

# send with your body message
emailHelp -BodyMessage $bodyMessage

# ---some script here---
$bodyMessage = "body message2.
emailHelp -BodyMessage $bodyMessage
```

**Ref:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.4

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I had something very similar but when calling the function I used the following, emailHelp -Body $bodyMessage. When I added the param in the function should I have used the name of the param when passing it to the function later.

Comment: Ur welcome. Yes, when you declare a parameter in a function using param ([string]$BodyMessage), you should use the same parameter name when passing values to the function (-BodyMessage).